# Wordpress template for custom post type subpage

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post types called "realestate". For the first level pages i create subpages which contain the information about the different appartments.

I created the single-realestate.php template file which non is used for page and subpage when i create them. Is it possible that the subpages automatically uses a specific template file?

Comment: Everything is possible

Comment: @Joachim Do you know how?